# If induced homomorphism of homologies of complex projective space is non zero then the map is surjective

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f \colon \mathbb{CP}^n \to \mathbb{CP}^n$ be a continuous function which induces a non-zero map $f_*$ on every Homology group $H_{2k} (\mathbb{CP}^n)$. Show that $f$ is surjective.

As we all know $H_{2k} (\mathbb{CP}^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, if $n \geq k$.

Thus if we look at the $2k$-th homology, $f_* : \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{Z}$ must be a multiplication by a scalar. i.e. $f_*(x) = c_k x$ (for $x$ the generator of $H_{2k} (\mathbb{CP}^n)$). By the assumption $c_k \neq 0$ for all $k \leq n$.

What else can we say?

Comment: You'll get better answers if you show what you've already considered and where you've got stuck.

Comment: Hint: you haven't made it clear what tools you have available, but you shouldn't need any special properties of $\Bbb{C}\Bbb{P}^n$ other than that it's a connected $2n$-manifold or of $f$ other than$H_{2n}(f)$ is non-zero.

Comment: I think you can probably try arguing by contradiction. If $f$ missed a point, could it really be nonzero on all homology groups?